# Turn multi-column text into a single longer column

Tags: bash, formatting

I am trying to find a way, in bash, to turn a text with mutliple columns to appear as 1 column.

For example, I have a text file like this

```
Key1 Val1  Key4 Val4  Key7 Val7
Key2 Val2  Key5 Val5
Key3 Val3  Key6 Val6
```

and I want to turn this into

```
Key1 Val1
Key2 Val2
Key3 Val3
Key4 Val4
Key5 Val5
Key6 Val6
Key7 Val7
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F"  " '{                         # double space delimiter
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                  # loop all fields
        a[i]=a[i] (a[i]==""?"":ORS) $i  # buffer to array a
}
END {                                   # in the end
    for(i=1;(i in a);i++)
        print a[i]                      # output the a array
}' file
```

Partial output:

```
Key1 Val1
Key2 Val2
Key3 Val3
Key4 Val4
...
```

<s>Using sed:</s>

```
$ sed 's/  /\n/g' file
```

Comment: I would prefer to maintain the order. Key1 then Key2...

Comment: Lol, did't even think about that. :D A sec.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `awk`, iterate over each field and add a new line every second word.

`awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {printf "%s ",$i; if(i%2==0 && i!=NF) print ""} print ""}`'

Answer (score 0):

You could try `grep` with `sort`

```
$ grep -o '\<\S* \S*\>' input_file | sort -n
Key1 Val1
Key2 Val2
Key3 Val3
Key4 Val4
Key5 Val5
Key6 Val6
Key7 Val7
```